# How to combine FAB with BottomAppBar without overlapping nav items?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, material-components-android, android-jetpack-compose

I am using Material's `BottomAppBar` as my BottomNav in my Jetpack Compose's App. But when I tried to dock my fab on the `BottomAppBar`, it covers the nav items as the screenshot shows. Is there any way that could auto-add a space beside the fab?

[image: Screenshot]

I want to implement this effect without adding `Space` between nav items manually, like the effect below shows:

[image: Desired effect]

Below is my code:

```
@Composable
fun TestApp() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = {
            MyBottomAppBar(navController = navController)
        },
        floatingActionButton = {
            FloatingActionButton(onClick = { }) {
                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Rounded.Add, contentDescription = "fab")
            }
        },
        floatingActionButtonPosition = FabPosition.Center,
        isFloatingActionButtonDocked = true,
    ) {
        NavHost(navController, startDestination = Screen.Bill.route) {
            composable(Screen.Bill.route) { BillScreen() }
            composable(Screen.Chart.route) { ChartScreen() }
            composable(Screen.Budget.route) { BudgetScreen() }
            composable(Screen.Account.route) { AccountScreen() }
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Composable
fun MyBottomAppBar(navController: NavController) {
    BottomAppBar(
        cutoutShape = CircleShape
    ) {
        val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
        val currentRoute = navBackStackEntry?.arguments?.getString(KEY_ROUTE)

        Screen.items.forEachIndexed { index, screen ->
            BottomNavigationItem(               
                selected = (currentRoute == screen.route),
                icon = { Icon(screen.iconRes, screen.route) },
                label = { Text(stringResource(id = screen.labelRes)) },
                onClick = {
                    navController.navigate(screen.route) {
                        popUpTo = navController.graph.startDestination
                        launchSingleTop = true
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `BottomNavigation` is a `Row` and all the `BottomNavigationItem` is `Box` with the `.weight(1f)` modifier in the `RowScope`.

You can add an "empty" element in the middle of your `Row` or `BottomNavigation` with the same size as the `BottomNavigationItem`.

For example something like:

```
bottomBar = {
            BottomAppBar(cutoutShape = fabShape) {
                BottomNavigation {
                    items.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
                        if (index != 2){ // 
                        BottomNavigationItem(
                            // your implementation
                        )} else {
                            //Empty BottomNavigationItem
                            BottomNavigationItem(
                                icon = {},
                                label = {  },
                                selected = false,
                                onClick = {  },
                                enabled = false
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        },
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add empty icon and make it as not clickable.  also make custom ripple effect.

---

[image]

[image]